# How do I change the user/password page on Drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I want to change the text from "User Account" to something else when users get to /user/password on my Drupal site.

I am very new to Drupal.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your drupal version for better assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever site you've put Drupal on, you can always find the login page by appending "?q=user" to the end of your URL -- e.g. http://www.somesite.com/?q=user.

But if you want to customize the login page, click here:

http://drupal.org/node/19855

Comment: This was not the answer I was looking for. I had to modify my custom user.module (abc_user.module) and add a hook to hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()

Comment: I do appreciate you getting back to me though. Thanks much.